# how do I disable triggering of a Azure DevOps build pipeline every time it is saved?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Not only is the build pipeline I save triggered, but all my others are triggered as well every time I edit the YAML of any of my pipelines. How might I make this not happen?  It's inconvenient to have to manually stop all the running jobs that automatically are spawned by the saving of one of my many pipelines.

LATER ON: The "answer" below doesn't really answer the question.  What I discovered is that the pipleline YAML is actually stored in the repository with the code it works on, so any change to a pipeline triggers all the pipelines triggered by changes to the repo.  This is why ALL the pipelines then go into action. It's not what I want, but at least I understand it.  I'm putting this here for anyone who stumbles across this via a search.

Comment: Are you using YAML or Classic? What triggers do you have on your pipelines?

Comment: multi-stage YAML for one pipeline and classic for one build pipeline

Answer (score 4):

> how do I disable triggering of a Azure DevOps build pipeline every time it is saved?

You can opt out of CI triggers entirely by specifying `trigger: none`.

Or you could set the specify trigger for each pipeline by filters, like: CI triggers, Batching CI runs, Paths:

[Build Azure Repos Git or TFS Git repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)

Besides, you could also [skipping CI for individual pushes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-pushes) by including `[skip ci]` in the message or description of any of the commits that are part of a push, and Azure Pipelines will skip running CI for this push. You can also use any of the following variations:

- `[skip ci] or [ci skip]`
- `skip-checks: true or skip-checks:true`
- `[skip azurepipelines] or [azurepipelines skip]`
- `[skip azpipelines] or [azpipelines skip]`
- `[skip azp] or [azp skip]`
- `***NO_CI***`

Comment: I added trigger: none to ALL of the pipelines i have written, and they still ALL are triggered whenever i edit any one of them. this is madness!  do people really use this stuff?  it's like unleashing the Sorcerer's Apprentice every time I want to make ANY change.

Comment: @GusMueller, Share one of your YAML in your question and have you edit the Triggers option in your pipeline?

Comment: i think i figured out what was going on:  all the pipelines are actually somehow stored in the git repo along with the code, so any change to any pipeline triggers all the pipelines to build.  that's not what one would want, but it makes sense now.

Comment: Were you able to fix it, @GusMueller?

Comment: yes, the problem was the trigger. when i started this, i didn't realize the pipeline ITSELF is in the repo (though you can't just create it with a .yml file, you have to create it with a web-based gui, so there is meta info that has to be there that nobody can see). so changes to the pipeline make the pipeline run. this was very confusing and it would've been helpful had this been mentioned in the docs i was reading as an issue that would come up.

Answer (score 1):

By default pipelines get triggered on each push of the code.
As other have suggested you can set `trigger: none` on each pipeline.

But if you want to change this behaviour on every pipeline is a very inconvenient solution.

What you can do instead is go in the **Project Settings** (of azure devops project) and then in the **Settings** section look for **Disable Implied YAML CI trigger** and enable it.

From now on, only pipelines that explicitly define the trigger section will run.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/pipelines/sprint-227-update#prevent-unintended-pipeline-runs) the brief documentation of this feature.

[image]